# Ordered field in which axiom of completeness is satisfied is set of real numbers

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I'm unexperienced in analysis, so I don't know how to approach these kind of problems.

If we're given ordered field in which axiom of completeness is satisfied, than it's a set of real numbers. Intuitievly, this is true, but I'm supposed to prove this using only axioms of real numbers.
Axiom of completeness implies that there are not any "gaps" or "missing points" in the real number line.

More formally, $\forall A, B \subset R$; A, B $\not=$ $\varnothing$; if $\forall  a \in$ A and $\forall  b \in$ B; $a \leq b$ than $\exists c;  $$a \leq c$ $\leq b$

Comment: Depends on which “axiom of completeness” you are working under. Perhaps you might specify what you understand by completeness. The $p$-adic fields are complete in the Cauchy-sequence sense…

Comment: Edited, I hope it is more clear now

Comment: What is an “algebraic field?” An “algebraic number field” never is complete, and the completion of one can be all of. $\mathbb C.$

Comment: Yes, I actually mean ordered field, sorry for the mistake, bad translation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of the proof that every complete ordered field is isomorphic to the reals. As the proof is quite long, I will try just to give  references where possible.  Let $K$ be our complete ordered field.

I will take "complete" to mean that every set that is non-empty and bounded above has a [supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum). This can easily be shown to be equivalent to your definition.

First of all we can embed the natural numbers $\Bbb{N}$ in $K$, by identifying $n \in \Bbb{N}$ with the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n 1$ in $K$. Using this we can identify $\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ with subrings of $k$. We can show that $K$ is [archimedean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Equivalent_definitions_of_Archimedean_ordered_field): for any $x, y > 0$ in $K$, there is $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $nx > y$. This follows from completeness (if it were false, $y$ would be an upper bound for the non-empty set $\{nx \mid n \in \Bbb{N}\}$, but it is not difficult to see that that set can have no supremum).

By a theorem of [Hölder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_H%C3%B6lder) any archimedean ordered abelian group is order-isomorphic to a subgroup of the additive group $(\Bbb{R}, +)$ of reals. So the additive group $(K, +)$ of $K$ is order-isomorphic to a subgroup $(K', +)$ of $(\Bbb{R}, +)$ and we may assume that $1 \in K$ maps to $1 \in \Bbb{R}$ under this order-isomorphism. Also, $K'$ contains arbitrarily small positive elements, because $1/n \in K$ must be mapped to $1/n \in \Bbb{R}$. This implies that $K'$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$.

As both $K'$ and $\Bbb{R}$  are complete, and $K'$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$, we must have that $K' = \Bbb{R}$ (a bounded non-empty set can't have two different suprema in a (totally) ordered set). So we have that the additive groups $(K, +)$ and $(\Bbb{R}, +)$ are order-isomorphic under an isomorphism $\iota : K \to \Bbb{R}$, that maps $1 \in K$ to $1 \in \Bbb{R}$.

It remains to show that the order-isomorphism $\iota$ between $(K, +)$ and $(\Bbb{R}, +)$ respects multiplication. To see this, you show that $\iota(ax) = a\iota(x)$ for every $a \in \Bbb{N}$ and $x \in K$ by an induction on $n$. Then you extend this to give $\iota(ax) = a\iota(x)$ for every $a \in \Bbb{Q}$. Using completeness this gives you that $\iota(ax) = \iota(a)\iota(x)$ for every $a, x \in K$.